# C: Double Pointers and Objective-C NSError Double Pointers Usage

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers, nserror, double-pointer

I happened to stumble upon posts here on SO regarding the double star (`**`) usage with `NSError`. Decided to dig it a little deeper, which led me revisiting `C`.

I have already **read many posts here** (not a duplicate here) on `NSError` and I understand why they do so.

So, I decided to write a little snippet in the IDE (Xcode) to see it myself in action.

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;

int *c = &a;
int *d = &b;

int **e = &d;

NSLog(@"Before: a is: %d b is: %d", a, b);

[self testSingleStar:c]; 
[self testDoubleStar:e]; 

NSLog(@"After: a is: %d b is: %d", a, b);
```

**Methods:**

```
- (void)testDoubleStar:(int**)x
{
    int anotherValue1 = 22;
    **x = anotherValue1;
}

- (void)testSingleStar:(int*)x
{
    int anotherValue2 = 33;
    *x = anotherValue2;
}
```

**Output:**

Before: a is: **10** b is: **20**

After: a is: **33** b is: **22**

Both values of `a` (via a single pointer) and `b` (via a double pointer) did get changed.

So, if we can change the value (of `a`) using ***only a single pointer***, why would we need to use a pointer to a pointer to `NSError` so that we could modify the `NSError` object in method call where `NSError` object is passed in its parameter (`&error`)?

**In addition:**

In regards to the above, passing something to the parameter in `C` is actually passing a copy to the parameter (even in the case of a single pointer only a copy of it will get passed), so anything change made within the scope of the method will not effect the original value passed to it (that's why they use a double star).

But the above sample, in which only a single pointer is used, seems to contradicts this because the value (namely `a` pointed to by a single pointer - `c`) did get changed?

Comment: Re-evaluate your tests using Objective-C object instances rather than primitives.

Comment: @trojanfoe Sure, will do. But even in the case of `C` a double pointer is needed to modify the original value within the scope of the method, but from the above sample, a single pointer suffice to accomplish that?

Comment: @trojanfoe Tried it. Can you tell me why it only works for primitives even with single pointer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you can't just have an NSError object... you can only deal with Objective-C objects by pointer... so while you could theoretically take a pointer to NSError and swap its contents... it would mess up encapsulation (other things could be relying on that data that used to be there.).

also just reassigning the pointer to a new value doesn't work, because it doesn't affect the callers version.

so while it seems tempting to:

```
-(void)method:(NSError *)errObject
{
    //something like
    errObject = [NSError errorWithBlah:@"blah"]; // this will only change the local variable errObject, not the callers version, that pointer is just copied by value. 
}
```

or

```
 /// not real code, didn't check to see if my params are in the correct places etc.
-(void)mangler:(NSError *)errObject
{
    //something like
    errObject = realloc(errObject,sizeof *errorObject);
    memcpy(errObject,[NSError new],sizeof NSError);

    // you have killed the old version that may be in use.
}
```

Comment: Things look fine, except missing casts and some parentheses. Going back to the `C` samples in my question regarding this: so, you're saying that I am not actually changing the value of `a` and `b` via the pointer (`c` and `e`, respectively).? I think so. BTW, +1 for `errorWithBlah:`. I like it.

Comment: yes you are changing a and b, by adding another layer of indirection, the same that you are doing with the NSError double pointer. you cant just pass `a` and `b` to another function/method because the change wont percolate back up, it happened just to the function local copy.

Comment: But there is only a single pointer to `a`. And I thought in `C` only  the copy of the original value is passed to the parameter in both pass-by-value and pass-by-ref (single pointer) cases. But it seems like a single pointer did change the value of `a`. No double pointer needed. Hence my question.

Comment: @Unheilig yeah but you can't change the actual contents of the NSError object, it is forbidden... you can only change which memory that pointer points to.

Comment: BTW, would you know why that would work for primitives but not objects?

Comment: because you can change the value of a scalar type in place and it won't affect other copies of that value, unlike an object.

Answer (score 4):

You can modify an external variable of type `foo` by providing a `foo *` to a function or method:

```
+ (void)doJobReturningInt(int *) { ... }

int a;
[MyClass doJobReturningInt:&a]; // may modify the value of the variable a;
```

So far, so good.

Now how do we declare a variable storing an NSError object? With the `NSError *` type:

```
NSError *error;
```

So if we want to modify it, we need to provide a pointer to its type, that is to say `NSError **`.

```
+ (void)doJobReturningError:(NSError **)outError { ... }

NSError *error;
[MyClass doJobReturningError:&error]; // may modify the value of the variable error;
```

See? This is the same situation: for modifying the type `foo`, provide a `foo*`.

Comment: Thanks for nice samples here. +1. Would upvote again, if I could.